# Is "lay my life" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I am aware of the phrase `lay down` but for my specific purpose, the word "down" would remove the dramatic effect because it makes the sentence a bit too long. So, would `lay my life` suffice?

Comment: Lay my life is grammatical. You don't specify what you want it to mean, so it is impossible to say whether it means what you want to say.

Answer (score 3):

In expressions involving 'lay down my/his/her/our/their live[s]', the important part is 'lay down', which is a phrasal transitive verb, meaning in this case, give up or sacrifice. While you can remove the 'down' or 'up' from **some** such phrasal verbs without removing the meaning, 'lay down' is not one of these. Your suggestion (omitting 'down') would remove the meaning and make the sentence nonsensical. Sometimes shortening is not possible without sacrificing meaning.

[Lay down (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lay-down)